# generalizations of Lambert function for the solution of equation

Tags: lambert-w

Is there a general method to get the solution of

$$ xf(x)=a,$$

where $f(x)$ is an smooth analytic function?

So the solution can be expressed as $ g(a)$ and $g(a)f(g(a))=a
$ for some function $g(x)$ which has a power expansion  $ g(x)= \sum_{n\ge0}c_{n}x^n$ at the origin.

For example if $ f(x)=\exp(x) $ we have the Lambert function.

Comment: Have you studied Lagrange inversion?

Comment: If $f(x)=\frac{g(x)}x$, then you want the inverse of any smooth analytic function, which is general. Also, please see [general way to solve transcendental equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/154769/is-there-a-general-way-to-solve-transcendental-equations)

Answer (score 0):

My answer is for solutions in [closed form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression).

$$xf(x)=a\tag{1}$$
$$F(x)=xf(x)$$

If $f$ is an algebraic function, equation (1) is an algebraic equation and we can use the corresponding solution methods.

If $f$ is a transcendental function, we don't know how to solve the equation for $x$ by rearranging by applying only finite numbers of [elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) we can read from the equation.

If there don't exist a representation for the function $F$ as a composition of elementary functions, $F$ doesn't have [partial inverses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function#Partial_inverses) that are elementary functions, and we need non-elementary functions therefore.

Lambert W and its similar functions are the oldest and simplest of the non-elementary functions for your problem.

Today we also have Generalized Lambert W and Hyper Lambert W.

and the functions of [Hector Vazquez-Leal / Mario Alberto Sandoval-Hernandez / Uriel Filobello-Ninoa 2020]:

[What are the closed-form inverses of $x \sinh(x), x \cosh(x), x \tanh(x), x\ \text{sech}(x), x \coth(x), x\ \text{csch}(x)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4602072/what-are-the-closed-form-inverses-of-x-sinhx-x-coshx-x-tanhx-x-te)

[What are the closed-form inverses of $x+\sinh(x)$, $x+\cosh(x)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4603882/what-are-the-closed-form-inverses-of-x-sinhx-x-coshx)